# EF Subquery (where column in first query includes values in another list)

Tags: entity-framework

hoping an EF/linq guru out there can help me out with what should be a pretty simple query (as it would be in SQL). Here is the pseudocode of what I am trying to do:

QUERY A:

```
 var query1 = FROM tableA in Models.TableAs
              select tableA
```

QUERY B:

```
var query2 = FROM tableB in Models.TableBs
             WHERE tableB.ColumnA IN (query1.results.columnB)
```

My actual queries are much more complicated and cannot be represented by a simple join. I need to actually run the first query to basically get a list of values to use to filter the values down in the second query. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe

```
var query1 = from tableA in Models.TableAs
          select tableA

var query2 = from tableB in Models.TableBs
         where query1.Any(ta=>tableB.ColumnA==ta.ColumnB);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at this from the wrong direction for Entity Framework.

In SQL, you'd write stuff like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA
WHERE TABLEA.COLUMNA IN (TABLEB.COLUMNB)
```

using IN.

If we have models like this:

```
public class TableA
{
    public TableBEntity TableB {get;set;}
}

public class TableB
{
    public IEnumerable<TableAEntity> TableA {get;set;}
}
```

In EF, try this way:

```
from myvar in context.TableB select myvar.TableA
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful in understanding how to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe either jure's query or this query will get you the same results, but I think they will generate different SQL and one will probably be faster than the other. You might try both to see which one gives better performance.

```
var query1 = from tableA in Models.TableAs
          select tableA.columnB;

var query2 = from tableB in Models.TableBs
         where query1.Contains(tableB.ColumnA)
         select tableB;
```

Comment: Thanks! You're correct, both this answer and the one by jure both return the correct results. I went with the option suggested by jure becuase it was easier for me to figure out how to make it work with comparing two columns.